how can i mansory galley with tailwind
How can I make the gallery with tailwind I added below? I'm an amateur programmer. I want to create the gallery below with tailwind, but I couldn't do it. I want it to look the same on a big screen as it does below.
design
import React from 'react'

const Photo = () => {
  return (
    <div className=" p-5">
    <div className="flex ">
      <div className="">
        <img src="/img/bg.jpg" alt="Background" className="h-[380px] w-[460px] ml-[250px] w-full h-auto object-cover rounded-lg" />
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <img src="/img/bg.jpg" alt="Background" className="h-[240px] w-[360px] ml-[24px] w-full h-auto object-cover rounded-lg" />
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <img src="/img/bg.jpg" alt="Background" className="h-[320px] w-[440px] ml-[24px] w-full h-auto object-cover rounded-lg" />
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <img src="/img/bg.jpg" alt="Background" className="h-[320px] w-[440px] ml-[24px] w-full h-auto object-cover rounded-lg" />
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <img src="/img/bg.jpg" alt="Background" className="h-[240px] w-[210px] ml-[24px] w-full h-auto object-cover rounded-lg" />
      </div>
      <div className="">
        <img src="/img/bg.jpg" alt="Background" className="h-[420px] w-[600px] ml-[24px] w-full h-auto object-cover rounded-lg" />
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
  )
}

export default Photo

